# What does the sign @^ in a package.json file mean

Tags: npm

What does the sign **@^** in a package.json file mean?

```
postcss-colormin@^4.0.3:
```

Comment: `name@version`, the caret is explained in the dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), the `@` represents the version while the `^` represents that the specified version should be compatible with whatever version `npm i` will install.

Your specific example will allow npm to install the latest version of `postcss-colormin` that is compatible with v4.0.3.